How can I remove an item on the main Pharo menu left over by a Roassal installation?
After an attempt to install Roassal a persistent menu item has been to the top level of the image's menu.
The menu label is Load full version and after searching the image it is coming from a RSWorldMenu menu06LoadFullVersionOn method which triggers the RSWorldMenu loadFullVersion event.
How do I remove this element from the main menu object which I suspect might fix the problem?

The main problem is the additional menu item or something else? I'm fuzzy on that.

@tukan Yes the main problem is the additional menu item.

I suppose you are using Pharo 12 (deduction from the messages you have shown us).

I would try a hack that could help (save the image before trying): Smalltalk globals removeKey: nil

If the above does not work you can try and play around with MenuRegistration>>reset

In old Pharo (like 6,8) you could find resetWorld menu. That is not available anymore.



I'm actually on Pharo 10 because I feel it strikes a good balance between being up to date and being able to try out the tutorials.

How do you enumerate the MenuRegistration items? MenuRegistration itemList and MenuRegistration allInstances return errors or nothing at all. MenuRegistration is described as creating a handler for PluggableMenuItemSpecs. My problem is it possible to know what global variable holds the PluggableMenuItemSpecs or PluggableMenuSpecs and delete the unwanted ones?
Another thing I have to consider is whether they are recreated my some code elsewhere in the system.
